# Python matplotlib code which i dont understand what code do

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I bought Machine Learning A-Z course by SuperDataScience. In logistic regression teacher gives a piece of code for visualization, which I don't understand this code.

I try to investigate this. I understand some of code. But actually I have some question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max()+1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max()+1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(("red","green")))

plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())

for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(("red","green"))(i), label = j)

plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Salary")
plt.title("Logistic regression prediction")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

- Prediction on `contourf`? I research for that, can't find anything
- Why prediction is reshaped? Is it necessary?
- `ListedColormap(("red","green"))(i)` in scatter?
- label in scatter? What is this?

Comment: try to run the code, see the results, then change some parts one by one and see the effect on the results. that's the only way to learn.

Comment: @lenik I already do that. Thanks for this a found answer to majority of questions. This ones are latest question which I cant find any.

Comment: there are two labels in your training set, the scatter plot supposed to show the data from the set, colored green or red depending on the label, and display the actual label.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mulitple input data points can have same prediction, hence plotting filled contours (contourf) can give a quick idea of the search space.
2. Look closely, its not predictions reshaped but the input values. It is carried out to make sure, we have the dimension of X consistent with our training data.
3. This is just to make sure plotting different colors to each class's datapoints.
4. label is given as classes(y) so that it will be shown as legends when we plot them.

Some similar examples are shown in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_discretization_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-discretization-classification-py) in sklearn user guide.